# How to reference mapping file in SharePoint to sgus

Tags: powershell

In ShareGate, anyone knows how to map users to a file instead of writing out each user mapping in the PowerShell script?

Found the answer. pls delete.

Comment: https://documentation.sharegate.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000641228-Import-User-And-Group-Mapping you can import sgug using above link